# Parse email verification error with Swift 2

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2

Hi I'm trying to verify the user email with parse, I been searching the entire web for hours and have found nothing. Everything else with parse is working great! but when I trying to check if the email verification is true, I get this error:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

basically I'm trying to check that first so I can change to a different viewController, the code that I'm using right now is this...

```
if user.objectForKey("emailVerified")!.boolValue == true
{
    performSegueWithIdentifier("tarjetaCredito",sender: self)
}
```

I been trying all type of code and I always get the same error, any help? I'm using Xcode 7.0 beta 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see “unexpectedly found nil” in Swift, you can trace it to an exclamation point. (Whether it’s a bare `!` or `as!` or `try!`, the exclamation point essentially says, “Hey compiler, I know you think an error *could* happen here, but I *know* it will never actually happen, so don’t force me to deal with the error case.”)

In your code, the `!` is right here:

```
if user.objectForKey("emailVerified")!.boolValue == true
                                     ⬆︎
```

…which means that the result of the expression `user.objectForKey("emailVerified")` must be nil. Figure out why that expression is nil, and you’ll have your answer.

If `user` is a Dictionary, then perhaps there is no value for the key `"emailVerified"`, and perhaps you are using the wrong key string. (Aside: you may be able to say `user["emailVerified"]` instead, depending on what the type of `user` is.)

Whatever the cause, printing out the value of `user` on the line before the crash is likely to help you diagnose the problem:

```
print("----------> user = ", user) 
if user.objectForKey("emailVerified")!.boolValue == true
...
```

In general, it is often good practice in Swift to avoid using `!` — or at least carefully consider why you are using it. If you determine that it is sometimes valid for that expression to evaluate to nil — for example, it might be nil if the email is not validated yet — then you might use `?` instead; for example:

```
if user.objectForKey("emailVerified")?.boolValue == true
```